# Need to print to cups-pdf from rmcobol program - how to configure terminfo?

Tags: linux, pdf

We have an accounting program that runs on `rmcobol` on linux. We configured the printers through `cups` to print to pdf by specifying the printers in `terminfo.cfg`, and would like to print to pdf using `cups-pdf` (other suggestions welcome). Bellow defines the printers in the `terminfo.cfg` file

```
DEFINE-DEVICE device=epson2 path='lpr -Pepson2' PIPE=yes
DEFINE-DEVICE device=cupspdf path='lpr -Pcupspdf' PIPE=yes
```

The epson2 printer is a network attached printered configured in cups, it is a matrix printer and works fine. However I cant get the `cupspdf` printer (also defined in cups) to accept print jobs.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: Does your `cupspdf` printer (supposedly defined in CUPS) print when you use the commandline or any other application (*not* 'rmcobol', whatever that is)?

Comment: How exactly is your `cupspdf` printer defined in CUPS? I'd first be interested in the output of these three commands: (1) `lpstat -v cupspdf` and (2) `ls -l /etc/cups/ppd/cupspdf.ppd` and (3) `grep cupsFilter /etc/cups/ppd/cupspdf.ppd`.